# Getting an Array from Controller Method, passing it to Javascript/JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I have this test method in my controller, in a C# MVC Project (using razor markup):

```
public virtual string[] TestArray(int id)
{
    string[] test = new string[] { "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5" };

    return test;
}
```

Is there any way to get this array into javascript?

Here is what I've tried:

```
function testArray(id) {
    $.get('Project/TestArray/' + id, function (data) {
        alert(data[0]);
    });
}
```

It goes without saying that this didn't work - I'm not great with javascript.

How can I correctly do what I'm describing?

**NOTE**: "Project" is the URL pattern for my Controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return Json from your controller

```
public virtual ActionResult TestArray(int id)
{
    string[] test = new string[] { "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5" };

    return Json(test, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Get a Json object in your js using [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

```
function testArray(id) {
    $.getJSON('Project/TestArray/' + id, function (data) {
        alert(data[0]);
    });
}
```

Comment: This silently fails, are there any page includes / references I need?

Comment: No, just JQuery. Is it hitting your controller?

Comment: sounds like a routing issue. Fire up Fiddler or similar and confirm the HTTP request is being sent as you expect it to be. This is flagged as virtual also, are you overidding it anywhere?

Comment: Requests are being sent, but the request throws two 401's and a 404. Mysterious. Theres no overrides I'm aware of.

Comment: Wow, I just noticed, I was missing a '/' before 'Project'... it works perfectly now. Thanks a lot for your help (and patience) - it works like a charm now... /embarassment

Comment: No Worries, glad to be of help

Answer (score 0):

Use instead an action returning a JSON element :

```
public JsonResult TestArray(int? id)
{
    string[] test = new string[] { "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5" };
    return Json(test, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```